# adding links to JavaScript image arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, hyperlink

I've got some code here for a slideshow that I need to add links to, it is a JavaScript image array that works fine but I am not sure how to add links to each picture.

I'm very newbie with JS.

```
var mygallery=new fadeSlideShow({
    wrapperid: "fadeshow1", //ID of blank DIV on page to house Slideshow
    dimensions: [200, 235], //width/height of gallery in pixels. Should reflect dimensions of largest image
    imagearray: [
        ["images_ads/image1.jpg"],
        ["images_ads/image2.jpg"],
        ["images_ads/image3.jpg"]
    ],
    displaymode: {type:'auto', pause:5000, cycles:0, wraparound:false},
    persist: false, //remember last viewed slide and recall within same session?
    fadeduration: 1000, //transition duration (milliseconds)
    descreveal: "ondemand",
    togglerid: ""
})
```

Comment: In your image array, by the way, you have an array within an array `[]` - you can remove the brackets around each image url

Comment: Oh hang on, nevermind, the slideshow plugin you're using may need it. What slideshow plugin are you using?

Comment: @Christian, it seems to be this one [Dynamic Drive `fadeSlideShow()`](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/fadeinslideshow.htm).

Comment: I would bet that those inner arrays are meant to allow for other params, and I wouldn't be surprised if one of them was a url param.

Comment: With that particular plugin, those are actually parameters, none of which are urls @ultranaut

Comment: If it is the one @DavidThomas linked above, then it looks to me like `imagearray` does in fact take an optional url as its second item in that inner array.

Comment: However, it would be useful for the OP to clarify which plugin it is he's using exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Dynamic Drive, the second key in the image array should be your URL value and the third value is the text you want to display
For instance:

```
["images_ads/image1.jpg", "http://www.stackoverflow.com", "Your text goes here"],
```

Comment: Thanks alot guys, that did the trick. I thought it would be simple but I don't really understand JS syntaxes.